# creating a bitmap pattern for a window's HBRUSH

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

Well, I sort of want to have sort of a faint striped pattern across a window... Just, 'cause it'd look nice. Anyways, I know I can just make a hatched brush, like so:

[window with red stripes on white background http://www.cityaftersix.ca/uploads/windowpattern.png](http://www.cityaftersix.ca/uploads/windowpattern.png)

however, I can only set the foreground color, and I don't know how to make the background not white (just use the default window color). I was poking around MSDN trying to figure out how to draw a bitmap which used the default background color and a slightly darker foreground color to go across the background of the window. How would I do this? Note that I'm working in emacs, in C--I don't have like a resource editor or anything like that... I'll be adding this in pure C.

Anyone know how this is done?

My hopes are that I can draw a simple 5x5 bitmap with code--so that `COLOR_BACKGROUND` is used each time it is drawn. Is there a way to get `COLOR_BACKGROUND`, darken that color, and then copy it into a new color?

---

## Alright, alright, I did it

I'll re-post my solution as an answer in a bit, but the issue was something weird:
My call to `GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE);` was returning a `COLORREF` in the format `0x00BBGGRR`, whereas `CreateBitmap();` was interpreting it as `0x00RRGGBB`... I mean, I just swapped the red and blue bytes, but is there some way to avoid this endianness confusion or is it just a quirk of windows'?

Also, how do I paint this brush onto static controls?

Comment: Intel is a little endian platform, are you coming from an environment which is big endian? Perhaps that explains the confusion?

Comment: Nope, this is all just on my laptop in Windows XP... It just seems like one function is putting the RGB values in a different order than the other function is reading them. If it was an issue of system endianness, wouldn't it be either, say, 0x00RRGGBB, or 0xBBGGRR00? or 0x00BBGGRR / 0xRRGGBB00

Comment: I think that CreateBitmap creates a device dependant bitmap - the format of how the bits are laid out in memory are up to the device driver. You probably want to create a device independant bitmap using CreateDIBSection - you can safely edit a DIB without needing to know the implementation details

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll look into that--but what troubles could I run into using CreateBitmap? I'm just creating it once and then painting it everywhere... Though I suppose one implementation detail is that the bitmap data has to be word aligned... could this be different on some systems or something? Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out and got it all working. 
To create the pattern, I first created a bitmap like so:

```
   COLORREF bg = GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    bg = RGB(GetBValue(bg), GetGValue(bg), GetRValue(bg));
    COLORREF fg = bg - 0x00151515; //slightly darker than the background color
    COLORREF bits[30] = {          //would be problematic I guess if the color
      bg, bg, bg, bg, fg,          //was originally less than 0x00151515
      bg, bg, bg, fg, bg,
      bg, bg, fg, bg, bg,
      bg, fg, bg, bg, bg,
      fg, bg, bg, bg, bg
    };
    HBITMAP hbm = CreateBitmap(5, 5, 1, sizeof(COLORREF) * 8, bits);
```

`GetSysColor()` was returning a color in the format 0x00BBGGRR (blue, green, red), but `CreateBitmap()` wanted a color in the format 0x00RRGGBB. So I just swapped the blue and red values in `bg`. I turned it into an HBRUSH like this:

```
hbr = CreatePatternBrush(hbm);
```

Anyways, this worked well except that the `STATIC` controls were overtop of it, and made it really ugly (all the empty space behind the text, and in parts of the control where there wasn't any text at all).

To make the `STATIC` controls transparent, I handled the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message (previously I was trying to send some sort of message to the control, to change the background like I would change the text with `WM_SETTEXT`). So I did this:

```
HBRUSH main_st_color_ev(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc, HWND hwndChild, int type){

  return stripes;

}
```

(stripes is a global HBRUSH to which I assigned the bitmap-brush I made previously)
This changed all that ugly empty space in the control to the brush I created. However the space directly behind the text turned WHITE. After scouring the internet, and MSDN, I made the following addition:

```
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: I think that this code is probably fragile - after a bit of research it seems that CreateBitmap creates a DDB (device dependant bitmap) - you shouldn't use it for editing. The layout of the bits in a DDB is up to the device driver. You should be creating a DIB instead. Not too confusing I hope

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CreateHatchBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183504(VS.85).aspx) for simple inbuilt patterns.  To create your own, you use 
[CreatePatternBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183508(VS.85).aspx).

To quote from MSDN:

> A brush created by using a monochrome (1 bit per pixel) bitmap has the text and background colors of the device context to which it is drawn. Pixels represented by a 0 bit are drawn with the current text color; pixels represented by a 1 bit are drawn with the current background color.

Which is I beleave what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, basically. But I don't really know what a device context is, and I still don't know how I would get the background color of the window, and then alter that value to create the foreground color

Comment: A device context is the thing you draw with in GDI. It represents memory, a screen a printer that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You get the current back colour of a device context by using [GetBkColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908419.aspx). You can get a device context compatible with the window using [GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx). To put it together, use something like this:

```
HDC dc=GetDC(hWnd);
COLORREF backColour=GetBkColor(dc);

// do something...

ReleaseDC(dc);
```

Comment: that looks a lot easier,
but,
I'm creating the brush in a function, which is used in the class for the window (it hasn't been registered or created yet).